# WPF ComboBox itemsSource not working in Prism MVVM

Tags: wpf, mvvm, data-binding, combobox, prism

I'm trying to get a list of items from DB and populate it in a `ComboBox` using
EntityFramework and Prism MVVM,

> it is populating the items but the **text is not appeared when I open the `ComboBox`**? did I do
>   something wrong in the below code.

And

> **Is this the right way to implement the MVVM Pattern?**

---

### please find UPDATE1 below:

CodeBehind:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    this.DataContext = new XViewModel();
 }
```

Model:

```
public class SpModel
{
    public string SpName { get; set; }
    public string SpID { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel:

```
public class XViewModel : BindableBase
{
    private List<SpModel> _spList;
    public List<SpModel> SpList
    {
        get { return _spList; }
        set { SetProperty(ref (_spList), value); }
    }
}

public XViewModel()
{
    FillDefaultData();
}

private void FillDefaultData()
{
    using (JContext dc = new JContext())
    {
        var query = (from sp in dc.Sps
                     select new SpModel()
                     {
                         SpID = sp.SpID.ToString(),
                         SpName = sp.SpName
                     }).ToList();

        if (query != null && query.Count() > 0)
            SpList = query;
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="ddlSp" Height="38" Padding="2"
          ItemsSource="{Binding SpList}"                                                     
          SelectedValuePath="SpID"          
          DisplayMemberPath="SpName" />
```

---

### UPDATE1

STYLE:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Border Name="Border"
                        SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter 
                                      TextBlock.FontSize="14"
                                      TextBlock.Foreground="Black"
                                      TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold">
                        <ContentPresenter.Content>
                            <Grid>
```

Problem in this line:

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" />
```

..

```
                            </Grid>
                        </ContentPresenter.Content>
                    </ContentPresenter>
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#B1B1B1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: There are already many articles in web answering the same questions. Please do a quick search once. (hint: INotifyPropertyChanged)

Comment: `INotifyPropertyChanged` is implemented here, btw (although not needed yet, as the list doesn't change after it is initially created). But I'd rename `SpModel` to `SpViewModel` and make its properties read-only. The code should work, though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't set the `Content` property of the `ContentPresenter` in the `ControlTemplate`:

```
<Style x:Key="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="OverridesDefaultStyle" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
                <Border Name="Border" SnapsToDevicePixels="true">
                    <ContentPresenter 
                                      TextBlock.FontSize="14"
                                      TextBlock.Foreground="Black"
                                      TextBlock.FontWeight="Bold" />
                </Border>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger Property="IsHighlighted" Value="true">
                        <Setter TargetName="Border" Property="Background" Value="#B1B1B1"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Comment: What if I want to add a custom style for the content ?

Comment: The ContentPresenter just presents the content. You can't use a ContentPresenter to "style the content".

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, and works. Definitely no need for `ObservableCollection` in this case. I believe you think the `ComboBox` is empty since you don't have a selection. Try adding this and you should see the first entry when you assign `SpList`:

```
<ComboBox ... SelectedIndex="0" />
```

Comment: You're right, but I realized that the problem is in the ComboBoxItems ContentPresenter style. Something wrong in the content binding.

Comment: I've updated the question with the current situation